# Angular lazy loading with query parameters not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

I am trying to use lazy loading with query parameters but it's not working. Here's an example.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-table-rnxpbk)
The real case is that I use a reactive search form and for every post I load a lazy module with a table presenting the results from my search.This stackblitz example is similar. I use 'index' as query parameter 
and trying to load DetailsModule everytime I select a row. Any help?

Comment: `route.snapshot.queryParams.index` route parameters and query parameters are on separate objects for obvious reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DetailsModule` gets loaded once you click any row (to see the details). For accessing `query parameters` use `queryParams`. I suggest to subscribe in `DetailsComponent` to `queryParams` like so:

```
constructor() {
  this.person$ = this._currentRoute.queryParams
    .pipe(
      switchMap(q => this._apiService.getPerson(q.index))
    )
  )
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-table-w9t27s?file=src/app/details/details.component.ts)